# Simulate 1600x900 resolution in 1920x1080 monitors

Tags: windows-7, resolution, graphics

In our company we have some 1920x1080 monitors. Those PCs are running Windows 7 and built in graphics card (Intel HD graphics).

For our client requirement, we need to test certain feature of a software in 1600x900 resolution. We've installed latest driver for Intel HD graphics in those machines. But we can't set 1600x900 resolution as it is not displayed in supported resolutions/modes.

Given this situation, how can we test the software (desktop software, not web app) in 1600x900 resolution in these PCs?

Comment: That's strange, same setup (using Win8 though), can set any resolution I want. Maybe still not the right drivers are set up? Did Intel Desktop Graphics tab appeared in display properties dialog?

Comment: Yes, the tab appeared.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on this site? http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-029478.htm

Comment: @Andreas: it works! thank you. you can post this comment as answer, i'll mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel offers an official documentation regarding this topic:

http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-029478.htm

Answer (score 0):

Did you try, instead of using the intel application to change resolution, to just use Right Click > Screen Resolution and set it through windows? If that doesn't work then it's really quite strange that it doesn't appear.

EDIT:

Just had an idea. If your application runs from a .exe you could try adding `-w1600 -h900`to the launch options?

EDIT 2:

To do that, create a shortcut of your .exe and in the shortcut field add the code from above after the last speech mark.

Comment: Setting custom window size is not enough because in client office, they'll have taskbar which will occupy certain height. So our software won't have full 900 pixels.